# Complex SQL Query Filter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table named CompApps and I wish to retrieve particular records based on a multiple condition query.  My SQL is very rusty and this is why I am asking on Stack Overflow.  What I need is to amend the SQL below to include a where clause that will exclude records that do not have any relevant information in the fields Interface, ExAPI, ExtraInfo, OpenCol.  That is, in the image of the current query results below I want rows `170, 173, 174, 175, 177, 182, 185, 190` and NOT rows that only have the value of None, N\A or an empty value in Interface, ExAPI, ExtraInfo, OpenCol

```
SELECT RefNum, Interface, ExAPI, ExtraInfo, OpenCol
FROM CompApps
```

[image]

Comment: Clean up the data, use NULL everywhere you have N/A or empty. Then do something like "where coalesce(c1, c2, c3, c4) is null".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or maybe like this

Correcting this according to dnoeth's comment:

```
SELECT RefNum, Interface, ExAPI, ExtraInfo, OpenCol
FROM CompApps
WHERE Interface NOT IN('None','N/A')
   OR ExAPI NOT IN('None','N/A')
   OR ExtraInfo NOT IN('None','N/A')
   OR OpenCol NOT IN('None','N/A');
```

Comment: You don't need to check for `IS NOT NULL` as `NOT IN` already removes the `NULLs`...

Comment: @dnoeth Thx a lot. I'm such a defensive programmer, that I've never noticed that... ***wonder*** I tried `declare @tbl table(i int); insert into @tbl values (1),(2),(NULL); select * from @tbl where i not in(1);` and you are right... The only thing I'm now thinking of is: Why is this so?

Comment: Because `(a NOT IN (x,y))` is a shortcut for `(value <> a AND value <> b)` and any comparison with NULL results in `unknown` which is `NOT TRUE`

Comment: @HoneyBadger: As there's a three-valued logic comparisons with NULL return `unknown` (the effect is usually the same as `false`, it's excluded).

Comment: @dnoeth, thx for beating me to the fairly obvious... Defensive as I am I think I've written a `x IS NOT NULL AND x NOT IN(blah)` always, never ran into errors :-) Anyway: Good to know!

Comment: @Shnugo Thanks Shnugo - I wasn't aware of the "NOT IN" functionality

Comment: @AJF It's a handy feature :-) Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    RefNum, Interface, ExAPI, ExtraInfo, OpenCol
FROM 
    CompApps
WHERE 
    (Interface IS NOT NULL AND (Interface !='None' AND Interface !='N/A')) 
OR 
    (ExAPI IS NOT NULL AND (ExAPI != 'None' AND  ExAPI != 'N/A')) 
OR 
    (ExtraInfo IS NOT NULL AND (ExtraInfo != 'None' AND  ExtraInfo != 'N/A')) 
OR 
    (OpenCol IS NOT NULL AND (OpenCol != 'None' AND OpenCol != 'N/A'))
```

Comment: If `Interface = 'None'` it will be accepted in your query, because of `Interface !='None' OR Interface !='N/A'`. `Interface` is not 'N/A', so it's returned in your output. So, no, it is not fine yet...

Comment: @Just because you've addressed me directly: I wasn't the downvoter... and HoneyBadger has already pointed to the flaws...

Comment: I don't think so, because **ColumName != 'a' OR ColumnName != 'b'** is also equivalent of saying **ColumnName NOT IN ('a', 'b')** (please, reconfirm as it works correct for me) @HoneyBadger

Comment: No, `Column not in ('a', 'b')` is equivalent to `Column <> 'a' AND Column <> 'b'`. The `AND` makes a world of difference. For example, if we say that interface = 'None': `Interface <> 'None' AND Interface <> 'N/A'` will exclude this record. With an `OR` it's included because one of the two conditions return true: `Interface <> 'N/A'`, the result of ` `Interface <> 'None'` doesn't matter because one of the two conditions must return `true`, not necessarily both of them as with `AND`.

Comment: I was mixing **IN()** with **NOT IN()**. The conversion rule in case of **IN** is {  is **IN(a,b)** equals **=a or =b** } while in case of **NOT IN** { is **NOT IN()** equals **!=a AND !=b** }

Answer (score 0):

```
where 
(
    (ISNULL(ExAPI, '') <> '' OR ExAPI <> 'N/A' OR ExAPI <> 'None')
    OR
    (ISNULL(ExtraInfo, '') <> '' OR ExtraInfo<> 'N/A' OR ExtraInfo<> 'None')
    OR
    (ISNULL(OpenCol, '') <> '' OR OpenCol<> 'N/A' OR OpenCol<> 'None')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT RefNum, Interface, ExAPI, ExtraInfo, OpenCol
FROM CompApps
WHERE (Interface NOT IN ('','None','N/A'))
   OR (ExAPI NOT IN ('','None','N/A'))
   OR (ExtraInfo NOT IN ('','None','N/A'))
   OR (OpenCol NOT IN ('','None','N/A'))
```

Comment: @Shnugo, thanx, and i think he need to exclude empty value also. (he is mentioned in the question *rows that only have the value of None, N\A or an empty value*)